# jQuery autocomplete on multiple fields

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

Surprisingly, I didn't find any answers to my question.

I want to make a form on jQuery with two fields.

1. City Code.
2. City Name.

and when I enter a city code and go out of the field.
I want an autocomplete on the city name.

I Installed the jQuery [Autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete).

and I have the following code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#field_localite").autocomplete('admin/ajax/npa', {
       extraParams: {
           npa: function() { return $("#field_npa").val(); }
       }
    });

    $("#field_npa").blur(function() {
        $("#field_localite").search();
    });
});
```

The problem is that the .search() method. doesnt launch the autocomplete.

I'm looking for a method to trigger this autocomplete search on the field.

do you know a way or a plugin able to do this search ?

thanks in advance

BTW : the PHP code behin is totally tested and works, it returns the data when doing the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it.

finally I did it another way.

I put the autocomplete on the city code field :

```
$("#field_npa").autocomplete(Drupal.settings.basePath+'admin/ajax/npa', {
   formatItem: formatItem,
   cacheLength: 1,
   minChars:4

}).result(function(event, data, formatted) {
    $("#field_localite").val(data[1]);
});

function formatItem(row) {
        return row[0] + " " + row[1];
}
```

and this did the trick as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#field_localite").autocomplete("search");` should do the trick.

Comment: Wait, are you talking about the jQueryUI Autocomplete?

Comment: no, I wasn't talking about the jQueryUI Autocomplete, but the one on bassistance.de